# Partially blocked form with javascript results in a security vulnerability

Tags: javascript, javascript-security

I have a huge form, with tons of input fields that should be filled by the system users. Some of those fields are blocked by a Javascript function, cause they are filled automatic by the system in some cases. Let me give you an example:

```
User code
Name
Surname
Address
SSN
Contact info
```

If the user provides a User code, contact infos are filled and blocked with `disabled="disabled"`.
If someone with wrong intentions access the page code and just erase `disabled="disabled"` he can fill blocked fields with wrong data. Theres any way that I can prevent this from happen only using Javascript?

Comment: No. Never trust data from the client. Validate on the back end **always**.

Comment: Javascript is client-side. That means that clients have full control over it. So you can't use it against them.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've thought. The guy who designed the system did everything with JS, and now i need to do something to revalidate all data on server side. :(

Comment: Always always always validate on the server side.

Comment: @AndreDuarte: Validating on the server side is **not** optional. Your original designer had no clue what they were doing.